# How do I find out what made my EC2 instance unreachable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For the second time in a week my EC2 instance suddenly become unreachable and I don't know what to do in this situation. The web server went down and I couldn't SSH into the box or ping it on either the elastic IP or the internal address. In the AWS console both the "System Status" and "Instance status" are fine, but there was a spike in the "CPU utilisation" at the exact same time it went down. On both occasions I rebooted the machine, but that isn't a solution.

Does anyone know how I can find out what went wrong and, more importantly, what should I do in this situation if it happens again?

Many thanks

Comment: Seems like its running out of resources, e.g. ram. Do you have CW agent install to monitor ram and disc usage?

Comment: @marcin No I don't (but I'll look into that now). Is there a log file that would show that I had run out of memory?

Comment: Don't think so. How large is the instance? Maybe you need to upgrade it?

Comment: what sort of process running in the instance? is it node application or something else?

Comment: It's a t2.small instance, but all it's running is one website in Apache. No node applications or anything else like that. The weird thing is that when I get a screenshot of the instance it just shows the login prompt as usual. Nothing to indicate there is anything wrong, but I just can't even SSH into it.

Comment: Either its the CPU or memory that triggers this issue. one way is to check CPU if there is spike then normal use then you can look into cpu or for memory you can install CW agent and sed memory metrics to CW

Comment: Thanks. There is definitely a spike in CPU at that time. This is the graph: https://imgur.com/a/8PwVBH1.  I'm just baffled as to what would have caused that to take the box down entirely. Is there a way to get more specific logs about what may have caused the CPU to spike?

Comment: link is not reachable. There are third party tool that can help, but one simple way is to set CW alarm around some CPU spike during starting spike do `SSH` and check `top` or you can explore Librato for metrics details

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into Librato!

Comment: There’s not really enough info to give a good answer. An alarm surrounding a spike is only going to tell you that the CPU has spiked, not the underlying cause. You could enable Cloudwatch logs on the instance and send all the logs to Cloudwatch and review them there. SSH might be something as simple as your IP has changed and your security groups do not permit your new IP.